# How to generate a well structured PDF with a SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, pdf, pdf-generation

Background: 
I have a SQL database residing in Microsoft SQL Server 2017 with 37 tables. All of these tables are related to faculty. It contains their personal details, publications,degrees, education, license information etc. It was originally designed in MS Access(recently migrated it to SQL) just to store faculty information. Later, faculty assistants started to use this DB to make CVs for their faculty manually using this information.

Problem:
As you can imagine, different people make CVs differently and there is no standard CV format. Also, now with greater number of faculty in the system, there is a need to automate this process.

Hence, I am looking for a way to design a process that fetches data from the SQL database and puts it into a specific format and generate a PDF. Confused about how to do it. It would be great if somebody can point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the context? Do you need to generate all the CVs as a one-time, or periodic operation, or do you need to generate them dynamically on demand?

Comment: I would have a look iText DITO. This product allows you to design your PDF and add databinding to your data using a browser-based editor. The difference here is that you will be having full control on your PDF file that you are going to generate. You can add conditions as well up to a certain level. note: I am working at iText.

Comment: @Onkel-j They need to be generated on demand. Whenever a faculty gets a new certification or something, their assistants put this data into the database and then they want their new CV to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this is with an SSRS report.  Format the report, use the database to fill in the dynamic elements, and when the report is executed, it can be exported to PDF with a click.